# Add JavaCV as a dependency, to run on a Raspberry PI?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, javacv

JavaCV documentation says I should use this to add JavaCV as a dependency to my project;

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.5.4'
}
```

The problem with this is that this includes all kinds of crap like runtime libs for Mac, Android, Windows, etc.

Which dependencies do I need to use JavaCV in my project, in a more non-bloated fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I've found that this is easily done using the "platform plugin of Gradle JavaCPP":

http://bytedeco.org/builds/

https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#the-platform-plugin

Using said plugin you can specify the target platform with : `gradle -PjavacppPlatform=linux-armhf` and only the needed platform dependencies will be used.

You also can look at the example:

https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp/tree/master/samples/javacv-demo

I've tried building the example and a uber-jar of "only" around 100Mb is generated.

I think you could also add some exclusions to eliminate unneeded libs and further reduce the size of the jar.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason the `gradle-javacpp` plugin doesn't provide libs for anything other than my host machine arch (linux-x86_64), when what I really need is arm64 arch.

Comment: Did you try passing this `-PjavacppPlatform=linux-arm64` to gradle? If you dont set javacppPlatform It will use host arch indeed.

Comment: How (where in the gradle scripts) do you do that, exactly?

Comment: I didn't do that in gradle script but in gradle invocation, for the example I ran `jar` task so I ran this from command line: `gradle -PjavacppPlatform=linux-arm64 jar`. I think it should be possible to do the same thing from gradle script, but I'm not sure how.